# Dynamic test name from data driven excel

Tags: java, testng, dataprovider

I use in my framework `testNG` with Data driven. All test data are taken from excel table and DataDriven return them as a two dimensional array e.g. Data[][].

My code looks like:

```java
@Test (DataDriven = "data")
public void testCase(Sting testName, String testData1, String results){
    String s = doSomething(testData1);
    Assert.assertTrue(s, results);
```

This is only an example, but every test parameter I got from excel column. I would like to add to testate name a name from `testName` parameter. Is it even possible? I use additionally `Listener` with `ITestListener` interface.

Comment: are you saying that each test case should be run with different test names?

Comment: Yes. I will change not only test name but test method name. I found a solution, where you can change test instance name, but the test name in html or xml output report is still untouched. Only test instance names are different.

Comment: you may [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68884939/edit) your question with these findings

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ITestContext` to set the test name.

```java
@Test(dataProvider = "data")
public void testCase(ITestContext ctx, Sting testName, String testData1, String results){
    ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().setName(testName);  
    String s = doSomething(testData1);
    Assert.assertTrue(s, results);
}
```